# NetBeans will not display image in Chrome with NetBeans Connector

Tags: html, netbeans

Hello I am brand new to coding and am trying my hand at html5 using NetBeans.  I am trying to load an image but the image doesn't load rather the alt text is displayed.

I have tried a .png and a .jpeg.  I have tried putting them in different subfolders with no success.  Also, I am using the palette to insert the code rather than typing it myself -- so I would think since NetBeans is actually generating the code that it would be correct.

Lastly, I think this problem is more NetBeans related than html coding errors.  See the screenshot of NetBeans and see the error messages in the Headers section.

How can I fix these errors and get my image to display on my website?

Thanks in advance for your help!

[Screenshot of NetBeans Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnMid.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to my problem.  If you look at the files in your project you will see a file titled "public_html".  Your images have to be in this folder or a subfolder of it to load the image to Chrome with the NetBeans Connector.